# Interface not being recognized

Tags: typescript

```
module FancyApp.Controllers {

    export interface IFancyViewModel {}

    export class FancyController implements IFancyViewModel {}

}

module FancyApp {

    ...
    $stateProvider
        .state("fancyState", {
            controller: [INSERT_VIEW_MODEL]
        });

}
```

When I denote `FancyApp.Controllers.FancyController` on `[INSERT_VIEW_MODEL]`, it compiles and runs fine, however typescript seems unable to find/recognize `IFancyViewModel`. What's the reason behind this?

Answer (score 0):

> however typescript seems unable to find/recognize IFancyViewModel

If it compiles fine then `TypeScript` has *done its* job. At *runtime* `interface`s are *erased* and do not exist.